# Doubly Linked List insertion Segmentation Fault - C

Tags: c, struct, doubly-linked-list

I have a homework to write First Come First Serve and Round Robin simulaion and compare them. I started of creating a linked list for making an event list. I have made insert and print_list functions, but couldn't make it work. My friend told me to use Doubly Linked List so I reacreated the linked list and am trying to make insert function work. I fixed most of the problems, but I can't find what's wrong with my insert function now. I get segmentation fault on my While loop statement, when I compare if inserting pointer data and the current pointer data. I have looked hrought my C book, which has the similar code as me and also through the Doubly Linked List Segmentation Fault -C questions here, but still couldn't get my error.

this is My Output

```
-bash-3.2$ ./main 3 100
please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.
1 2 3 4
something
something
DONE1
DONE2
DONE3
DONE4
Segmentation fault
```

as the test4 (DONE4) is printed and the next test is not, it means that I have an error in this part

```
while((currentptr->arrivaltime < newpointer->arrivaltime) && currentptr != NULL)
```

can you please help me? What is wrong with my code?

```
struct event {
   struct event *next;
   int processid;
   int arrivaltime;
   int cputime;
};
typedef struct event Event;
typedef Event *eventPtr;

Event create_node(int processid, int arrivaltime, int cputime);
void add_event(Event *newpointer, eventPtr *eventlist);
void print_node(Event node);
void print_eventlist(Event *eventlist);
Event get_nextevent(Event *eventlist);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int sourcenum,a,b,c,i;
Event tempevent;
eventPtr eventlist = NULL;
print_eventlist(&(*eventlist));
char* sources,timeSlice;
if(argc != 3)
printf("Proper usage is: main.c sources time-slice\n");
else
{
    sourcenum = atoi(argv[1]);
    timeSlice = atoi(argv[2]);
    for(i = 0; i < sourcenum ; i++)
    {
          //print_eventlist(&(*eventlist));
          printf("please enter the process-id, arrival-time and cpu-time.\n");
          scanf("%d %d %d",&a, &b, &c);
          printf("something\n");
          tempevent = create_node(a,b,c);
          print
          printf("something\n");
          add_event(&tempevent, &eventlist);
    }

}
return 0;
}


void add_event(Event *newpointer, eventPtr *eventlist)     //insert
{
 printf("DONE1\n");
 eventPtr currentptr, prevptr;
 printf("DONE2\n");
 prevptr = NULL;
 printf("DONE3\n");
 currentptr = *eventlist;
 printf("DONE4\n");
 while((currentptr->arrivaltime < newpointer->arrivaltime) && currentptr != NULL)                  /*on every loop previous and current pointer gets upgraded*/
 {
         printf("DONEW\n");
         prevptr = currentptr;
         currentptr = currentptr->next;   
 }
 printf("DONEW\n");
 if(prevptr != NULL)
 {
     printf("DONEW\n");
     prevptr->next = newpointer;
     newpointer->next = currentptr;
 }
 else
 {
     printf("DONEW\n");
     newpointer->next = *eventlist;                      //?????
     *eventlist = newpointer;
 }
 printf("DONE\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that the problem is most likely in

```
while((currentptr->arrivaltime < newpointer->arrivaltime) && currentptr != NULL)
```

The fact that you want to test for `currentptr!=NULL` implies that it might be NULL. But if it is then the earlier part of your condition will fail. Test for `NULL` first, THEN make the second half of the comparison...:

```
while(currentptr != NULL && (currentptr->arrivaltime < newpointer->arrivaltime))
```

Comment: It worked, Thank you so much. Should I take down the question or leave it? I am not really experienced at stackoverflow and I don't know if this question should stay on the page.

Comment: You are welcome. This was not a "bad" question - I see no reason why you should take it down. We have community moderation for that sort of thing - people vote (invisible to you) when they think a question doesn't belong. No worries. Be happy. Learn lots. Then start sharing your experience by answering others' questions (or your own if you solve a particularly gnarly problem).

Answer (score 1):

```
eventPtr eventlist = NULL;

add_event(&tempevent, &eventlist);
{
    currentptr = *eventlist;  //currentptr == NULL at this point
    ...............
    while(currentptr->arrivaltime ....)  // Segmentation
}
```

In your code, the "eventlist = NULL" passed into "add_event". This is the reason of the Segmentation.

I think you should do "malloc()" to get a entry for "eventlist" before use it in "add_event".